How to generate a JSON string with XPath 3.1
I have some text in a node, for example:
<xml>&lt;Hello world "&amp;" foo bar&gt;</xml>

I would like to process string(/xml) and JSON-escape it so that the result would be something like:
"<Hello world \"&\" foo bar>"

How can I do it with XPath 3.1?

Is there a particular language you are writing in or are you trying to accomplish this entirely within XPath?
Can you give a more complex example, maybe a nested object, of what you want to convert to JSON?

You can use serialize(string(xml), map{'method': 'json'})
